# Почему метод объекта не является функцией?

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу валидацию формы. Вот код:

```js
const Validator = function(options) {
  const form = document.getElementById(options.id),
    elementsForm = [...form.elements].filter(item => item.tagName !== 'BUTTON'),
    error = new Set(),
    pattern = {
      email: /^\w+@\w+\.\w+$/,
      phone: /^\+?[78]([()-]*\d){10}$/
    },

    validorMethod = {
      notEmpty(elem) {
        if (elem.value.trim() === "") {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      pattern(elem, pattern) {
        return pattern.test(elem.value);
      }
    }

  const isValid = (elem) => {
    const method = options.method[elem.id];
    if (method !== undefined) {
      return method.every(item => validorMethod[item[0]](elem, pattern[item[1]]));
    }
    return true;
  };
  const checkIt = (event) => {
    let target = event.target;
    if (isValid(target)) {
      showSuccess(target);
      error.delete(target);
    } else {
      showError(target);
      error.add(target);
    }
    console.log(error);
  };
  elementsForm.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', checkIt);
  });

  const showError = (elem) => {
    elem.classList.remove('validator_success');
    elem.classList.add('validator_error');
    if (!elem.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('error-message')) {
      const errorDiv = document.createElement('div');
      errorDiv.textContent = "You have an error there";
      errorDiv.classList.add('error-message');
      elem.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', errorDiv);
    }
  };

  const showSuccess = (elem) => {
    elem.classList.remove('validator_error');
    elem.classList.add('validator_success');
    if (elem.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('error-message')) {
      elem.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  };

  for (let key in options.pattern) {
    pattern[key] = options.pattern[key];
  };

  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    elementsForm.forEach((elem) => {
      checkIt({
        target: elem
      });
    });
    if (error.size) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
};

const valid = new Validator({
  id: 'myform',
  pattern: {
    phone: /^\+380\w{9}/
  },
  method: {
    'email': [
      ['notEmpty'],
      ['patern', 'email']
    ],
    'phone': [
      ['notEmpty'],
      ['patern', 'phone']
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<section>
  <form id="myform">
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <label for="phone">phone</label>
    <input type="text " name="phone" id="phone">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button type="reset">reset</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Когда я ввожу некорректные данные возникает следующая ошибка:

> validator.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: validorMethod[item[0]] is not a function
>   at validator.js:25
>   at Array.every ()
>   at isValid (validator.js:25)
>   at HTMLInputElement.checkIt (validator.js:31)

---

Вот и на github залил https://github.com/Streammer/form-validation.git

Comment: какие данные ты вводишь, с каким параметром вызывается функция?

Comment: Ответом на ваш вопрос будет значение `item[0]` в момент генерации исключения. Поставьте breakpoint и подловите этот момент. А так, `options` осталось за кадром, поэтому нам трудно судить о причине. Но скорее всего просто потому, что в том контексте `validorMethod[item[0]]` было равно `undefined`

Comment: options я добавляю в html коде между тегами script. Вот он                                            
   `<script>
  const valid = new Validator(
   {
    id: 'myform',
    pattern: {
     phone:/^\+380\w{9}/
    },
    method: {
     'email': [
      ['notEmpty'],
      ['patern', 'email']
     ],
     'phone': [
      ['notEmpty'],
      ['patern', 'phone']
     ]
    }
   }
  );
 </script>`      И item[0]  у меня равен notEmpty

Comment: Но если я вывожу `return method.every(item => console.log(typeof(validorMethod[item[0]])));` То выводит в консоль function.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код для `options`. Еще лучше, если ваш код будет в сниппете, что бы мы могли запустить и увидеть ошибку.

Comment: Поправил вопрос, добавил код для options.